# code-oss (Code - OSS) on FreeBSD-CURRENT: renderer process crashing, the application can no longer open my workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

FreeBSD [editors/vscode](https://www.freshports.org/editors/vscode/) recently began crashing for me at startup.

Removed, reinstalled, no improvement.

I wondered whether removal of `rapid_render.json` would work around the issue, it did not.

Another user of the system can start the application without crashing.

Please: how might I resolve the issue?

```
grahamperrin@mowa219-gjp4-8570p:~ % less ~/.config/Code\ -\ OSS/Backups/workspaces.json
{"rootURIWorkspaces":[],"folderURIWorkspaces":[],"emptyWorkspaceInfos":[{"backupFolder":"1579922206882"}],"emptyWorkspaces":["1579922206882"]}
grahamperrin@mowa219-gjp4-8570p:~ % less ~/.config/Code\ -\ OSS/logs/20201217T074443/main.log
[2020-12-17 07:44:44.168] [main] [info] update#ctor - updates are disabled as there is no update URL
[2020-12-17 07:44:48.938] [main] [error] [VS Code]: renderer process crashed!
[2020-12-17 07:44:59.171] [main] [error] [VS Code]: renderer process crashed!
[2020-12-17 07:45:09.432] [main] [error] [VS Code]: renderer process crashed!
grahamperrin@mowa219-gjp4-8570p:~ % ls -ahlrt ~/.config/Code\ -\ OSS/
total 174
drwx------    3 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     3B 26 Dec  2019 Code Cache
-rw-r--r--    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin    36B 26 Dec  2019 machineid
drwxr-xr-x    5 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     6B  2 Jan  2020 User
drwxr-xr-x    2 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     2B 25 Jan  2020 Workspaces
drwxr-xr-x    3 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     3B  4 Jul 06:00 clp
drwx------    2 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     7B 16 Jul 10:57 GPUCache
-rw-------    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     0B 26 Sep 09:08 .org.chromium.Chromium.uev8QR
drwxr-xr-x    3 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     3B 26 Sep 17:24 CachedData
drwxr-xr-x    3 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     4B 20 Nov 17:57 Backups
drwxr-xr-x    2 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     4B  6 Dec 19:43 CachedExtensions
drwx------    3 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   284B 14 Dec 11:17 Cache
-rw-------    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   2.0K 16 Dec 05:56 TransportSecurity
-rw-------    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin    20K 16 Dec 05:57 Cookies
-rw-------    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     0B 16 Dec 05:57 Cookies-journal
-rw-r--r--    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   446B 16 Dec 05:58 rapid_render.json
-rw-------    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   2.8K 16 Dec 05:58 .org.chromium.Chromium.eOeolK
-rw-------    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   2.8K 16 Dec 14:06 .org.chromium.Chromium.a8khF7
-rw-------    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     0B 16 Dec 14:20 .org.chromium.Chromium.fuVPBw
-rw-------    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   2.8K 16 Dec 20:47 .org.chromium.Chromium.ICOK4n
-rw-------    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   2.8K 16 Dec 21:56 .org.chromium.Chromium.21Y7f0
-rw-------    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   2.8K 17 Dec 05:00 .org.chromium.Chromium.Ro52fi
-rw-------    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   2.8K 17 Dec 05:29 .org.chromium.Chromium.J1dZMh
-rw-------    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     0B 17 Dec 06:35 .org.chromium.Chromium.P3gDsE
-rw-r--r--    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin    75K 17 Dec 06:42 storage.json
-rw-------    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     0B 17 Dec 06:42 .org.chromium.Chromium.bQdorG
-rw-------    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   2.8K 17 Dec 06:47 Network Persistent State
drwx------    2 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     8B 17 Dec 06:47 Session Storage
-rw-------    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     0B 17 Dec 07:32 .org.chromium.Chromium.AQtB07
-rw-------    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     0B 17 Dec 07:39 .org.chromium.Chromium.FT0hEj
drwx------    3 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     3B 17 Dec 07:44 blob_storage
-rw-r--r--    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin    12K 17 Dec 07:44 languagepacks.json
drwxr-xr-x   12 grahamperrin  grahamperrin    12B 17 Dec 07:44 logs
-rw-------    1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     0B 17 Dec 07:45 .org.chromium.Chromium.KK5qMG
drwx------   14 grahamperrin  grahamperrin    35B 17 Dec 07:45 .
drwxr-xr-x  100 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   264B 17 Dec 08:11 ..
grahamperrin@mowa219-gjp4-8570p:~ % ls -ahlrRt ~/.config/Code\ -\ OSS/Backups/
total 10
drwxr-xr-x   3 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     4B 20 Nov 17:57 .
drwxr-xr-x   4 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     4B 28 Nov 06:29 1579922206882
-rw-r--r--   1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   142B 17 Dec 07:44 workspaces.json
drwx------  14 grahamperrin  grahamperrin    35B 17 Dec 07:45 ..

/home/grahamperrin/.config/Code - OSS/Backups/1579922206882:
total 10
drwxr-xr-x  3 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     4B 20 Nov 17:57 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     4B 28 Nov 06:29 .
drwxr-xr-x  2 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     2B 10 Dec 15:14 file
drwxr-xr-x  2 grahamperrin  grahamperrin    14B 16 Dec 05:56 untitled

/home/grahamperrin/.config/Code - OSS/Backups/1579922206882/file:
total 1
drwxr-xr-x  4 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     4B 28 Nov 06:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     2B 10 Dec 15:14 .

/home/grahamperrin/.config/Code - OSS/Backups/1579922206882/untitled:
total 63
drwxr-xr-x  4 grahamperrin  grahamperrin     4B 28 Nov 06:29 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   551B 16 Dec 05:56 b2bd717a77da570a5c596af6934cadc7
-rw-r--r--  1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   652B 16 Dec 05:56 0ea542ac1d82a4ad63b68365c0270c53
-rw-r--r--  1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   1.6K 16 Dec 05:56 109fbbd2da4537c9ab3475d44131d9f8
-rw-r--r--  1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   2.5K 16 Dec 05:56 2f0c80a5829bd778936522620f8dc240
-rw-r--r--  1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   317B 16 Dec 05:56 387795c86765346eca0c041bac00348b
-rw-r--r--  1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   902B 16 Dec 05:56 3e42341b68b5e3d2ec3af201cdb461a0
-rw-r--r--  1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   242B 16 Dec 05:56 5a4df22f62baaaa5684aacc5372f2b14
-rw-r--r--  1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   115B 16 Dec 05:56 8526d8318dcbce336eae5b633e7f2b20
-rw-r--r--  1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   4.4K 16 Dec 05:56 85a25ec2bf655a740ef43253dcde2851
-rw-r--r--  1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   538B 16 Dec 05:56 bba55dec34aadf10f7d0655859dd3ade
-rw-r--r--  1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   238B 16 Dec 05:56 d45b5ea50824ae45a6f3cae14bb85e07
-rw-r--r--  1 grahamperrin  grahamperrin   184B 16 Dec 05:56 e5e5e2d9b68c3afbc119011b57046d5a
drwxr-xr-x  2 grahamperrin  grahamperrin    14B 16 Dec 05:56 .
grahamperrin@mowa219-gjp4-8570p:~ % less ~/.config/Code\ -\ OSS/Backups/1579922206882/untitled/b2bd717a77da570a5c596af6934cadc7 
untitled:Untitled-4
net user Administrator | find /i "Password last set"

runas /user:Administrator powershell



Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs

cd "c:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\" ; date ; whoami ; query user ; wget https://extranet.brighton.ac.uk/public/download/BIGIPComponentInstaller.msi -OutFile BIGIPComponentInstaller.msi ; wget https://extranet.brighton.ac.uk/public/download/f5vpn_setup.exe -OutFile f5vpn_setup.exe ; dir . | sort LastWriteTime | Out-Default ; winver ; .\BIGIPComponentInstaller.msi ; .\f5vpn_setup.exe ; cd ~

grahamperrin@mowa219-gjp4-8570p:~ % less ~/.config/Code\ -\ OSS/rapid_render.json 
{"id":"monaco-parts-splash","colorInfo":{"foreground":"#cccccc","editorBackground":"#1e1e1e","titleBarBackground":"#3c3c3c","activityBarBackground":"#333333","sideBarBackground":"#252526","statusBarBackground":"#007acc","statusBarNoFolderBackground":"#68217a"},"layoutInfo":{"sideBarSide":"left","editorPartMinWidth":220,"titleBarHeight":0,"activityBarWidth":48,"sideBarWidth":170,"statusBarHeight":22,"windowBorder":false},"baseTheme":"vs-dark"}
grahamperrin@mowa219-gjp4-8570p:~ % rm ~/.config/Code\ -\ OSS/rapid_render.json
grahamperrin@mowa219-gjp4-8570p:~ % code-oss --verbose
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:09.207Z] Starting VS Code
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:09.224Z] from: /usr/local/share/code-oss/resources/app
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:09.225Z] args: {
  _: [],
  diff: false,
  add: false,
  goto: false,
  'new-window': false,
  'reuse-window': false,
  wait: false,
  help: false,
  'list-extensions': false,
  'show-versions': false,
  version: false,
  verbose: true,
  status: false,
  'prof-startup': false,
  'disable-extensions': false,
  'disable-gpu': false,
  telemetry: false,
  logExtensionHostCommunication: false,
  'skip-release-notes': false,
  'disable-restore-windows': false,
  'disable-telemetry': false,
  'disable-updates': false,
  'disable-crash-reporter': false,
  'disable-user-env-probe': false,
  'skip-add-to-recently-opened': false,
  'unity-launch': false,
  'open-url': false,
  'file-write': false,
  'file-chmod': false,
  'driver-verbose': false,
  force: false,
  'do-not-sync': false,
  trace: false,
  'force-user-env': false,
  'no-proxy-server': false,
  nolazy: false,
  'force-renderer-accessibility': false,
  'ignore-certificate-errors': false,
  'allow-insecure-localhost': false
}
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:09.230Z] Resolving machine identifier...
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:09.231Z] Resolved machine identifier: 76d5dcb36bedd2b6a2ae2706b11c68da607ea2bce16973ed535e6bfdec09baac (trueMachineId: undefined)
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:09.659Z] [storage state.vscdb] open(/home/grahamperrin/.config/Code - OSS/User/globalStorage/state.vscdb, retryOnBusy: true)
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:09.662Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 2)
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:09.664Z] windowsManager#open
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:09.667Z] window#validateWindowState: validating window state on 2 display(s) { mode: 0, x: 0, y: 0, width: 1133, height: 510 }
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:09.668Z] window#validateWindowState: multi-monitor working area { x: 0, y: 0, width: 1920, height: 1080 }
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:09.669Z] window#ctor: using window state { mode: 0, x: 0, y: 0, width: 1133, height: 510 }
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:10.515Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 3)
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:10.516Z] update#ctor - updates are disabled as there is no update URL
[6407:1217/081711.075297:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:11.808Z] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): SELECT * FROM ItemTable
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:11.810Z] [storage state.vscdb] getItems(): 41 rows
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:11.913Z] [storage state.vscdb] updateItems(): insert(Map(3) {storage.serviceMachineId => 735a3a8a-3134-4ebb-abad-e6b9359a2727, telemetry.lastSessionDate => Thu, 17 Dec 2020 07:44:45 GMT, telemetry.currentSessionDate => Thu, 17 Dec 2020 08:17:11 GMT}), delete(Set(0) {})
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:11.914Z] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): BEGIN TRANSACTION
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:11.915Z] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): INSERT INTO ItemTable VALUES ('storage.serviceMachineId','735a3a8a-3134-4ebb-abad-e6b9359a2727'),('telemetry.lastSessionDate','Thu, 17 Dec 2020 07:44:45 GMT'),('telemetry.currentSessionDate','Thu, 17 Dec 2020 08:17:11 GMT')
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:11.916Z] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): END TRANSACTION
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:13.521Z] getShellEnvironment: running on CLI, skipping
[6407:1217/081713.710517:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
(node:7307) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:7307) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:7307) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:7307) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:17.184Z] Shared process: IPC ready
(node:9633) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:9633) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:17.813Z] Shared process: init ready
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:20.956Z] [VS Code]: renderer process crashed!
(node:9971) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:9971) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:9971) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:9971) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:28.334Z] [VS Code]: renderer process crashed!
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:29.665Z] Lifecycle#window.on('closed') - window ID 1
[main 2020-12-17T08:17:29.666Z] Lifecycle#onWillShutdown.fire()
[6407:1217/081729.728513:WARNING:x11_util.cc(1399)] X error received: serial 478, error_code 173 (GLXBadWindow), request_code 153, minor_code 32 (X_GLXDestroyWindow)
[6407:1217/081729.728617:WARNING:x11_util.cc(1399)] X error received: serial 482, error_code 3 (BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)), request_code 4, minor_code 0 (X_DestroyWindow)
grahamperrin@mowa219-gjp4-8570p:~ % less ~/.config/Code\ -\ OSS/.org.chromium.Chromium.eOeolK
{"net":{"http_server_properties":{"servers":[{"isolation":[],"server":"https://davidwang.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://ajshort.gallery.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://stkb.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://ionutvmi.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://ms-vscode.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://ms-python.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://ms-ceintl.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://ms-iot.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://ms-iot.gallery.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://bgforge.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://classix.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://vmssoftwareinc.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://killerall.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://siamz.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://alexhenriquepv.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://leighlondon.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://ionutvmi.gallery.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://miusuncle.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://yedhrab.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://rjarouche.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://neptunedesign.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://jakob101.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://dariofuzinato.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://sryze.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://flesler.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://stkb.gallery.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://ms-ceintl.gallery.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://tomashubelbauer.gallerycdn.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://tomashubelbauer.gallery.vsassets.io","supports_spdy":true},{"isolation":[],"server":"https://marketplace.visualstudio.com","supports_spdy":true}],"version":5},"network_qualities":{"CAASABiAgICA+P////8B":"4G","CAYSABiAgICA+P////8B":"Offline"}}}
grahamperrin@mowa219-gjp4-8570p:~ % code-oss --disable-extensions --verbose
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:01.005Z] Starting VS Code
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:01.011Z] from: /usr/local/share/code-oss/resources/app
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:01.011Z] args: {
  _: [],
  diff: false,
  add: false,
  goto: false,
  'new-window': false,
  'reuse-window': false,
  wait: false,
  help: false,
  'list-extensions': false,
  'show-versions': false,
  version: false,
  verbose: true,
  status: false,
  'prof-startup': false,
  'disable-extensions': true,
  'disable-gpu': false,
  telemetry: false,
  logExtensionHostCommunication: false,
  'skip-release-notes': false,
  'disable-restore-windows': false,
  'disable-telemetry': false,
  'disable-updates': false,
  'disable-crash-reporter': false,
  'disable-user-env-probe': false,
  'skip-add-to-recently-opened': false,
  'unity-launch': false,
  'open-url': false,
  'file-write': false,
  'file-chmod': false,
  'driver-verbose': false,
  force: false,
  'do-not-sync': false,
  trace: false,
  'force-user-env': false,
  'no-proxy-server': false,
  nolazy: false,
  'force-renderer-accessibility': false,
  'ignore-certificate-errors': false,
  'allow-insecure-localhost': false
}
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:01.016Z] Resolving machine identifier...
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:01.016Z] Resolved machine identifier: 76d5dcb36bedd2b6a2ae2706b11c68da607ea2bce16973ed535e6bfdec09baac (trueMachineId: undefined)
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:01.143Z] [storage state.vscdb] open(/home/grahamperrin/.config/Code - OSS/User/globalStorage/state.vscdb, retryOnBusy: true)
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:01.146Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 2)
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:01.148Z] windowsManager#open
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:01.151Z] window#validateWindowState: validating window state on 2 display(s) { mode: 0, x: 0, y: 0, width: 1133, height: 510 }
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:01.152Z] window#validateWindowState: multi-monitor working area { x: 0, y: 0, width: 1920, height: 1080 }
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:01.153Z] window#ctor: using window state { mode: 0, x: 0, y: 0, width: 1133, height: 510 }
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:01.681Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 3)
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:01.684Z] update#ctor - updates are disabled as there is no update URL
[13433:1217/081902.366547:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:02.583Z] [storage state.vscdb] getItems(): 41 rows
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:02.585Z] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): SELECT * FROM ItemTable
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:02.686Z] [storage state.vscdb] updateItems(): insert(Map(3) {storage.serviceMachineId => 735a3a8a-3134-4ebb-abad-e6b9359a2727, telemetry.lastSessionDate => Thu, 17 Dec 2020 08:17:11 GMT, telemetry.currentSessionDate => Thu, 17 Dec 2020 08:19:02 GMT}), delete(Set(0) {})
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:02.689Z] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): BEGIN TRANSACTION
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:02.692Z] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): INSERT INTO ItemTable VALUES ('storage.serviceMachineId','735a3a8a-3134-4ebb-abad-e6b9359a2727'),('telemetry.lastSessionDate','Thu, 17 Dec 2020 08:17:11 GMT'),('telemetry.currentSessionDate','Thu, 17 Dec 2020 08:19:02 GMT')
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:02.693Z] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): END TRANSACTION
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:02.864Z] getShellEnvironment: running on CLI, skipping
(node:13490) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:13490) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:13490) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:13490) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:04.147Z] [VS Code]: renderer process crashed!
[13433:1217/081904.745930:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:06.291Z] Shared process: IPC ready
(node:13567) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:13567) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:06.356Z] Shared process: init ready
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:07.353Z] Lifecycle#window.on('closed') - window ID 1
[main 2020-12-17T08:19:07.353Z] Lifecycle#onWillShutdown.fire()
grahamperrin@mowa219-gjp4-8570p:~ % gdb /usr/local/bin/code-oss ./code-oss.core
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.1 [GDB v10.1 for FreeBSD]
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-portbld-freebsd13.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
"0x7fffffffe080s": not in executable format: file format not recognized
[New LWP 102724]
[New LWP 116825]
[New LWP 116826]
[New LWP 116827]
[New LWP 116828]
[New LWP 116829]
[New LWP 116830]
[New LWP 116831]
[New LWP 116832]
[New LWP 116833]
[New LWP 116834]
[New LWP 116835]
[New LWP 116836]
[New LWP 116838]
[New LWP 116839]
[New LWP 116840]
[New LWP 116841]
[New LWP 116842]
[New LWP 116843]
[New LWP 116844]
[New LWP 116845]
[New LWP 116846]
[New LWP 116847]
[New LWP 116848]
[New LWP 116849]
[New LWP 116850]
[New LWP 116851]
[New LWP 116867]
[New LWP 116888]
Core was generated by `code-oss: --disable-extensions --verbose --no-sandbox'.
Program terminated with signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
#0  0x00000000025d0c77 in ?? ()
[Current thread is 1 (LWP 102724)]
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000025d0c77 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000081432a0c0 in ?? ()
#2  0x000000081227a608 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007fffffffd750 in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000002c5e17b in ?? ()
#5  0x000000081227a608 in ?? ()
#6  0x000000081227a620 in ?? ()
#7  0x000000081432a0c0 in ?? ()
#8  0x000000081227a620 in ?? ()
#9  0x000000081227bff0 in ?? ()
#10 0x0000000007740100 in ?? ()
#11 0x000000081432a0c0 in ?? ()
#12 0x00000008133b6730 in ?? ()
#13 0x00000008133b6730 in ?? ()
#14 0x00000008133b6740 in ?? ()
#15 0xecf3e8d0b6254a2e in ?? ()
#16 0x000000080f6d9620 in ?? ()
#17 0x000000081227a608 in ?? ()
#18 0x00007fffffffd7e8 in ?? ()
#19 0x0000000000000005 in ?? ()
#20 0x0000000001a3c432 in ?? ()
#21 0x00007fffffffd7d0 in ?? ()
#22 0x0000000002c5e06e in ?? ()
#23 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) q
grahamperrin@mowa219-gjp4-8570p:~ % pkg query '%o %v %R' vscode
editors/vscode 1.46.1 FreeBSD
grahamperrin@mowa219-gjp4-8570p:~ % uname -v
FreeBSD 13.0-CURRENT #74 r368589: Sun Dec 13 07:55:46 GMT 2020     root@mowa219-gjp4-8570p:/usr/obj/usr/src/amd64.amd64/sys/GENERIC-NODEBUG 
grahamperrin@mowa219-gjp4-8570p:~ %
```

– unfortunately, nothing useful in the backtrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug reported:

[Code - OSS crashed consistently at start time – renderer process crashed! – until after I removed cached data workbench.desktop.main-17c1ea9255cc303c9339b9c2ce2b4a02.code · Issue #113069 · microsoft/vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/113069)

With the bugged `~/.config/Code - OSS` directory (restored from a backup):

[image: A Dolphin view of CachedData and Backups]

[image: A more detailed Dolphin view of CachedData]

After removing the offending file, a first run of the application:

[image: Screenshot]

> Extension host terminated unexpectedly.

This occurred a few seconds after every run of the application.

[image: Screenshot of developer tools]

Output from `code-oss --verbose` at https://pastebin.com/gPXMNdrv

After disabling all possible extensions ([English (United Kingdom) Language Pack for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-CEINTL.vscode-language-pack-en-GB) can not be disabled), then re-enabling all: touch wood, no recurrence of *Extension host terminated unexpectedly*.